# Why is there an error saying 'attempt to index nil with 'Position''?

Tags: error-handling, lua, roblox

I do not know what is happening here. I'm trying to make randomly generated terrain as a test and this code is one of my experiments(I'm adding code for curvature later) but it Says 'attempt to index nil with 'Position'' AND I have no idea how to fix it.

```
local Block = game.ReplicatedStorage.Auto_generated
local Plosition = 1
local Line = 1
local Lite = 1

print('1')
Block.Position = Vector3.new(251,35,261)
BlockClone.Position = Vector3.new(Line,pos,Lite)

while Plosition <= 100 do
    print('2')
    BlockClone = Block:Clone()
    BlockClone.Parent = game.Workspace
    pos = math.random(0,10)
    BlockClone.Position = Vector3.new(Line,pos,Lite)
    Line = Line + 10
    Plosition = Plosition + 1
    if Line == 10 then
        Lite = Lite + 10
        print('3')
    end
    if Line == 20 then
        Lite = Lite + 10
    end
    if Line == 30 then
        Lite = Lite + 10
    end
    if Line == 40 then
        Lite = Lite + 10
    end
    if Line == 50 then
        Lite = Lite + 10
    end
    if Line == 60 then
        Lite = Lite + 10
    end
    if Line == 70 then
        Lite = Lite + 10
    end
    if Line == 80 then
        Lite = Lite + 10
    end
    if Line == 90 then
        Lite = Lite + 10
    end
    wait(1)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
BlockClone.Position = Vector3.new(Line,pos,Lite)
```

In that line (the one ABOVE the while), BlockClone is undefined.

you only define it two lines below in

```
BlockClone = Block:Clone()
```

Answer (score -1):

I think it's because of the code : Plosition = 1 at the top

Comment: Though it is a misspelling, the same identifier is used later on in the code.